# How can I control all my website's requests?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, algorithm, performance

I need to manage my website's requests. Because of both I need to detect suspect requests and block that IP and calculate the number of users which visit my website.

So I've created a table like this:

```
// requests
+----+----------------+-------------+
| id |  UserId_or_IP  |  unix_time  |
+----+----------------+-------------+
| 1  | 12353          | 1339412843  |
| 2  | 23353          | 1339412864  |
| 3  | 178.253.29.175 | 1339412894  |
| 4  | 3422           | 1339412899  |
| 5  | 342232         | 1339412906  |
| 6  | 2353           | 1339412906  |
| 7  | 7785           | 1339412951  |
| 8  | 148.23.29.109  | 1339413640  |
| 9  | 178.253.29.175 | 1339413621  |
| 10 | 5462           | 1339414490  |
| 11 | 342232         | 1339414923  |
| 12 | 178.253.29.175 | 1339419901  |
| 13 | 8007           | 1339424860  |
| 14 | 8007           | 1339424822  |
| 15 | 2353           | 1339424902  |
+----+----------------+-------------+
```

And I insert a new row into that table for every request *(opening every page of my website means one request)*.

And here is my query in the `index.php`: (`index.php` is a page which all pages pass from it)

```
INSERT INTO requests (id, UserId_or_IP, unix_time)
            VALUES   (NULL, :id_or_ip, UNIX_TIME());
```

---

**What's my problem?** That query makes my webpage-loading slow. Because there is an `INSERT` query before loading every page. Is there any better approach to handle website's requests?

Comment: Use a queuing system to do this logging for you that way is isn't blocking

Comment: "Is there a better approach?" -- yes.  Your web server should already have access logs that you can parse offline to measure these statistics.  For apache, it's typically in `/var/log/httpd/access_log` on a Unix-based system.  For stopping intrusive visitors, check out `fail2ban`

Comment: As an aside, I'd suggest avoiding having a column whose contents could be two different things.  Instead, have a "userid" and a "ip" column; put NULL in userid when it is not a logged-in user.  (But you should still use your web server's built-in logging for your goals)

Comment: @Lotharyx I see .. May you please write an answer under my question and explain your idea completely?

Comment: I'll be happy to; are you actually using apache?

Comment: @Lotharyx Not really, I'm using Nginx

Comment: You're positive that the slowdown is your MySQL insert? Are you performing any additional calculations after the insert has been performed? If you comment out just the insert then does the speed improve by a lot?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I think if I remove that insert then the speed will be much faster.

Comment: It's not very wise to place blame on code which has not been proven to be slow. I highly recommend that you actually test your theory or else you will create additional problems for yourself.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Fine .. Just tell me what I'm doing (inserting a row for each request) is a correct approach?

Comment: It sounds fine, no one is going to come and arrest you for doing that. Like I said though, you need to actually benchmark your code before placing blame. It does not matter what I think, what you think, or what anyone else thinks; the benchmarking numbers won't lie to you and will tell you if your approach is good or bad.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus You know, my code isn't slow. I just guess it will be slow in future *(when my website has a lot of online users)*. So I'm trying to avoid of being slow. May you please tell me how can I manage my website's requests?

Comment: No, I did not know that because you did not state that in your question. Your statement `What's my problem? That query makes my webpage-loading slow.` is extremely misleading and you are obviously trying to start a conversation rather than fix a problem. That's not how this site works.

Comment: That trivial `INSERT` is taking 1 millisecond, maybe 2.  Use `microtime(true)` around it to demonstrate that it is _not_ a performance issue.  Meanwhile pepper your code with timings to see what _is_ the perf problem.

Comment: When your site becomes so busy that you are delivering hundreds of web pages per _second_, you will have other performance issues than this `INSERT`.

Comment: @RickJames You are right .. that `INSERT` query is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider instead using the logs that your web server already generates.  For example, in a file called `access_log`, the web server Apache writes lines that look like this:

```
80.82.70.24 - - [19/Jun/2016:07:26:44 -0400] "GET http://httpheader.net/ HTTP/1.1" 401 481 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.28) Gecko/20120306 Firefox/3.6.28 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)"
```

The configuration of your server will determine the structure in this log file.  This example from my default Apache installation includes the IP of the request, the time it occurred, the actual request, the code the server sent back (in this case, 401-not found), and the browser that made the request.  There are a lot of examples on the internet of using programs like Perl to parse a web server log file and generate statistics.

You commented that you're using Nginx, so you'll have to read about what logs Nginx will create.

Comment: You're welcome!  Thanks for the upvote; come back and comment more if you try this and have questions.

Comment: I think parsing a file would be much harder than working with database. So I believe storing each request into database seems better to me. Am I right?

Comment: The answer, as it so often is, is "it depends."  Our Asker may be more familiar with handling databases, so he wants to use a database, but now he finds that his database query has a negative impact on his website's performance.  I think in this case, it is not "better".  In other cases, it could very well be "better" to use the database instead of the log files.

Comment: The 'heavy hitters' read the logs.  And they deal with _billions_ of page views per day.